# Unable to Add Cores to Virtual Machine HYPER-V

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019

I created a VM on Hyper-V running on Windows Server 2019, with 8GB of RAM and 2 Virtual processors as you can see below.

[image]

However it appears that there's no options to add cores to the processor, as you can see below I only have 1 which Im planning to increase to 2.

Is it possible to increase this on a Hyper-V VM,
I've already tried and browse countless pages on google but I cant find any solution.

[image: This is what it looks like inside the VM]

[image]

EDIT:

The host server running this VM has 6 Cores

Comment: If the VM is running, you cannot change the processor setting.

Comment: I can shut off the VM, but I need to increase the cores as shown in the screenshots